# On the proof of Theorem 13.8 of Titchmarsh

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Denote by $\zeta$ the Riemann zeta function, and let $\sigma, T \in \mathbb{R}^+$ where $\sigma \geq 1/2$. I'm going through the proof of Theorem 13.8 of Titchmarsh's *The theory of the Riemann zeta function*. At some point in the proof, it is claimed without proof (presumably because its a trivial result) that the residue of the integral

$$\int_{\Re(s)=5} \frac{\log \zeta(s + iT)}{4 -(s+\sigma)^2} \mathrm{d}s$$ at the pole $s=1-iT$ is $\ll T^{-2}$. How can this be proved ?

**ADDENDUM:** Maybe my question isn't explicitly clear, hence the votes for closure.

But i'm asking for the *exact* expression of the quantity (integral) that Titchmarsh claims to be $\ll T^{-2}$.

Comment: This has close votes for "missing context". However, asking for help in a single step of a specific proof, with a citation, seems fine context. So maybe the close voters could suggest some improvements, rather than making the OP guess?