# On the residue of $\log \zeta(s+iT)$ at $s=1-iT$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Let $\zeta$ denote the Riemann zeta function and $T \in \mathbb{R}$. What is the residue of $\log \zeta(s + iT)$ at $s=1-iT$ ?

My attempt: Since $\zeta(z)$ has a simple pole at $z=1$ with residue $1$, note that Res $_{s=1-iT} \log \zeta (s + iT) = \log $ Res$_{s=1} \log \zeta(s)$ =$\log 1=0$ ?

**ADDENDUM:** Below are replies to the comments, somehow I can't post a comment.

@Conrad: Yes, $\log \zeta(s+iT)$ is not continuously defined around $s=1-iT$. However, making a detour around the point $s=1-iT$ produces some integral over some circular contour, which can be evaluated as the residue at that point.

PS: This question is a reformulation of [On the proof of Theorem 13.8 of Titchmarsh](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4214124/704680,which) was said to be unclear.

@Greg Martin, thanks. Can you please kindly answer this [On the proof of Theorem 13.8 of Titchmarsh](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4214124/704680) ?

Comment: $\log \zeta(s + iT)$ has a logarithmic singularity at $s=1-iT$ so it is not continuously defined on a neighborhood of $s=1-iT$ and in particular the notion of residue doesn't make sense; usually one cuts a horizontal segment from $s=1-iT$ to deal with that

Comment: One can indeed evaluate a(n almost) circular integral of this function, but I would still not call that a "residue". For example, it will depend upon the radius of the circle.